# Symfony: deal with "%" escaped symbols in URL

Tags: url, escaping, symfony-1.4

I have Symfony 1.4 web-application.
Let's say my app is hosted on example.com and there is FAQ page there.

When I refer to my app like this: http://example.com/faq#faq1 everything works fine.
But when "#" is escaped: http://example.com/faq%23faq1

I see the following message in log produced by symfony:

```
[err] {sfError404Exception} Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/faq#faq1" (/).
```

So, it looks like Symfony recognizes there is "#" but fails to route it correctly.

**routing.yml:**

```
faq:
  url: /faq
  param: { module: static, action: faq }
  requirements:
    sf_method: [get]
```

How do I make Symfony to route URL with escaped characters correctly?

Comment: How to you build your url? (paste the code where you use `url_for` and/or `link_to`)

Comment: This is not an internal site link, so url_for/link_for is not used. This link (http://example.com/faq#fa1 is posted on external resources on the Web. Some of those resources automatically escape "#" sign like "%23". Then, when that external resource users click on the link, they see 404 page of my web-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a Symfony problem. It's not your problem. The problem come from people who escape `#`.

I took few examples:

- OK - http://www.rue89.com/faq#5.7
- NOK - http://www.rue89.com/faq%235.7
- OK - http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq1.html#WhatIs
- NOK - http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq1.html%23WhatIs
- OK - http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-general.html#register
- NOK - http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-general.html%23register

Etc ... etc ...

Comment: Thank you for your research. I think, I will try to leverage Apache mod_rewrite rules to deal with this escaped character somehow. Any ideas on how to do this are appreciated.